# From where do I Press the PLUS and MINUS Keys?

Tags: keyboard

Where's the Plus and Minus key on the standard QWERTY English keyboard? I use a an Hp i5 laptop.

Comment: i5 is not a model of laptop, its a CPU. CPUs do not have keyboards... and you have the machine with you but can't be bothered to look at the keys or the manual? Finally, QWERTY does not dictate the layout of all keys and the special character keys.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a real question.

Answer (score 3):

In a standard 104 key keyboard, they are next to the numerical <kbd>0</kbd> key on the top row of a standard QWERTY keyboard, and require the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to be pressed.  Laptops tend to follow the standard QWERTY layout, although some keys do get moved.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On a US (as well as UK)keyboard.

For + press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>. This is the key to the left of backspace.

For - press <kbd>-</kbd>. This is the key to the left of <kbd>=</kbd>.